# qt compile error including QtCore resulting in utf-8 error

Tags: qt

Getting the following error in my library when trying to compile a library that is linking against Qt.

```
/opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/QtCore:1:1: error: source file is not valid UTF-8
```

File.cxx is

```cpp
#include <QtCore>
int main(){
 return 0;
}
```

Using mac ports

Unsure if this is some weird mac problem or?

```
/opt/local/bin/clang++-mp-11 -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_LINUX_OS_ -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600  -I/opt/local/libexec/qt5/include -isystem /opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework -isystem /opt/local/libexec/qt5/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers -isystem /opt/local/libexec/qt5/./mkspecs/macx-clang -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -Werror -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT fie.cxx.obj -MF file.cxx.obj.d -o file.cxx.obj -c file.cxx
```

Ive gotten similar results using xcode's compiler

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/CC
```

Comment: can you explain more details ? !!

Comment: Did you notice `-std=c99` in your exposed command line? That looks strange. I would have expected `-std=c++17` (at least, for the recent qt versions).

Comment: Added more comments.  It seems like its including what I think is qt's precompiled header as ascii text rather than decoding it.

Not terribly familiar with pre compiled headers.

Comment: I suspect I need to wait until IT can update my mac to the latest version, and then download the latest version of xcode.